# Write file to AppDataDirectory fails with no error

Tags: maui

I'm trying to create a text file in the AppDataDirectory folder that will be read back in later, but the file doesn't get created and the "files" folder is also not created.  I am currently testing with the Android emulator.

This is my code.  I've tried several methods, but no work.

```
        public async Task CopyFileToAppDataDirectory(string filename, string filedata)
        {
            // Covert filedata to a stream
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(filedata);
            using Stream inputStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

            string targetFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, filename);

            // Copy the file to the AppDataDirectory
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(targetFile, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await inputStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }

            // This method didn't work either
            //using FileStream outputStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(targetFile);
            //using StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream);
            //await sWriter.WriteAsync(filedata);

            return;
        }
```

I've tried using the WriteAsync and the CopyToAsync functions.

I'm using the Android emulator.  In the Android/data path I can see that a folder with my project name was created that contains a cache folder, but the files folder doesn't get created, nor the file I am trying to write.

When I try and read the file that I just tried to write I get the error: Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: '/data/user/0/com.veland.dailytasks/files/myTaskHistory.json'

This is the code I am using to read the file:

```
        public async Task<string> ReadTextFile(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                using Stream fileStream = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(filePath);
                using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);

                return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
            catch
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the Android/data path I can see that a folder with my project name was created that contains a cache folder, but the files folder doesn't get created, nor the file I am trying to write.

In fact, you have writen the file successfully. This is because the file with path `Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, filename)` can't be found by the Android System File Manager. But you can find it by the Android Studio's Device File Explorer. You can try to read the file to check if you write it successfully or not.

In addtion, if you want to create the file in the Android/data/.../projectname path, you can use `Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("").AbsolutePath`, such as:

```
string targetFile;
#if ANDROID
targetFile = Path.Combine(Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("").AbsolutePath, filename);
#else
targetFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, filename);
#endif
```

====================

The `FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync` is used to read the bundled file not the device local file. You can use the following code to read the file:

```
        public async Task<string> ReadTextFile(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                return sr.ReadToEnd();
            };
            }
            catch
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: I edited my question to show that I get an error when I try and read the file, so I know the creation of the file is not working.

Comment: The FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync is used to read the bundled file. Please check the update part in my answer. @EricV.

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses.  That solved my problem.  That worked to read the file.  This is my first mobile app and I was stumped by what seemed like such a simple process.

Comment: I found that I can use Await ReadToEndAsync() instead of ReadToEnd() to keep it Async.